# How are application classes/methods made available to java tests

Tags: java, maven, junit

In my recent role, I transitioned from C to Java. Our project has a standard java project structure as laid out by Apache Maven. I am able to run Junit tests from Intellij with no problems.

But I am curious about how the application logic spread across  /src/main/ is made available to the test logic in /src/test.

Is Unit testing framework responsible for this? or build tool creates a temporary jar which includes test classes along with application classes as governed by their respective package structures?

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Google "classpath". The **tl;dr** is that the classpath is a list of locations where a JVM will look for classes to load. Maven will compile productions code (`src/main/java`) into one location and test code (`src/test/java`) into another location and when you run the tests the maven testing plugin will put both of those targets onto the classpath making both production code and test code accessible. There's a lot more details and nuance to it, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am curious about how the application logic spread across /src/main/ is made available to the test logic in /src/test.
>
> Is Unit testing framework responsible for this?

No.

> or build tool creates a temporary jar which includes test classes
> along with application classes as governed by their respective package
> structures?

You could configure a build that would create a temporary jar file which includes test classes along with application classes, but that is not the normal thing.  Normally the build tool (Maven in your case) will compile all of the code to `.class` files and put all of those `.class` files on the CLASSPATH when the tests are run.  All classes that are available on the CLASSPATH will be accessible in the tests when tests are run.

Comment: Thanks. I came across resources saying, to have package private classes accessible from tests, create a similar package structure in test as well. So i was thinking the maven keeps application and test files under one package (given if they both have similar package structure). Is that the case?

Comment: No.  The author of the code dictates the package, not the build tool.  At the top of all of your source files you should have a `package` statement, like `package com.objectcomputing.training;`.  In general, that source file should be defined in a directory below your source root that matches the package structure, like `src/main/java/com/objectcomputing/training/SomeClass.java`.